# Gradle java-test-fixtures plugin with custom source and test set

Tags: java, gradle, build.gradle, gradle-plugin, java-test-fixtures

So I have a multimodule java project the structure of each module is as follows

```
A[module root]
--- main[source set]
--- testFixtures
--- testsrc[test source set]
--- build.gradle
B[module root]
--- main[source set]
--- testsrc[test source set]
--- build.gradle
```

Now when I build the module A the -test-fixtures jar that is generated is empty. My ultimate aim is to use the test helper classes in module A to be consumed by tests in module B.

So my question is will test-fixtures work with this structure.